# Programmatically create a list via REST in SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

**Problem:** Creating the list fails with a 403. "The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again."

**Environment:** SP Online (v16.0.0.23821), JavaScript limited by typescript, wrapped in an SPFx.

**more information:** User has rights to add and delete lists in the UI, successful REST list item CRUDs in same app, $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val() returns null, $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').length returns 0, the 'fetch("/_api/contextInfo", {' returns a value that looks like a valid context. example `0x22E59328225C10E5DAF77AF2668D9FAC52305355FFEE4E9D16CB1BC5B523C3114DE1E71FBD7739E3D12C7BBDFFA1F330106D60AABBA46F6C1163EBB9C5B9EDA2,08 Jul 2023 14:11:32 -0000`

I have tried several iterations of code and this is the closest I have gotten. Many online examples in plain ol javascript have suggested the use of $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(), I have found the object `__REQUESTDIGEST` is missing/empty in my SPFx environment and so I am fetching the context in a more manual way.

Help on what I am missing or doing wrong would be appreciated.

**The Code:**

```
createSharePointList(listTitle) {
var siteUrl = common.myWebUrl(); //returns 'https://mysite.sharepoint.com/teams/myteam'
var listUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists";

// Create the list metadata
var listMetadata = {
    "__metadata": { "type": "SP.List" },
    "BaseTemplate": 100,
    "Title": listTitle
};

fetch("/_api/contextInfo", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    }
}).then(contextResponse => {

    if (contextResponse.ok) {

        contextResponse.json().then(responseJson => {

            // get the form digest value that you _would_ have gotten from the missing $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
            var requestDigest = responseJson.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue; // Returns value as expected 

            // request the list build 
            $.ajax({
                url: listUrl,
                type: "POST",
                credentials: 'same-origin',
                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                data: JSON.stringify(listMetadata),
                headers: {
                    "X-RequestDigest": requestDigest,
                    "accept": "application/json",
                    "content-type": "application/json",
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("List created successfully.");
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log("Error creating list: ");
                    console.dir(error);
                }
            });

        })
    }
});
```

}

Comment: any reason you're using jquery instead of spHttpClient? it handles the request digest for you. https://www.vrdmn.com/2016/08/making-post-request-to-sharepoint-from.html

Comment: Or use SP PnP JS for creating new lists, simple and easier code. Check: https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/lists/#add-list

Comment: First: thank you both for your time! Consensus is add another black box. I'll check them out.

Comment: Let me know if you need any help with using PnP JS for creating new lists.